# Android app crashes on Device Boot

Tags: android

I am working on an Application that requires to start a `BackgroundService` on Android Boot

This is the code that I am using to start the `BroadcastReceiver` on Android Boot

```
public class StartOnBootService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try
        {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
            serviceIntent.setAction("com.package.myApplicationPackage.BackgroundService");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `BackgroundService.class`

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      //code to execute when the service is first created
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "BACKGROUND SERVICE STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      //code to execute when the service is shutting down
   }

   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
      //code to execute when the service is starting up
   }
}
```

This is the error log that I managed to snipe from the CatLog while my Android was Booting.

```
12-21 10:28:01.279: E/EmbeddedLogger(1710): App crashed! Process: com.package.myApplicationPackage
12-21 10:28:01.289: E/EmbeddedLogger(1710): App crashed! Package: com.package.myApplicationPackage v1 (1.0)
12-21 10:28:01.289: E/EmbeddedLogger(1710): Application Label: myApp Label
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
        </service>
        <service android:name=".BackgroundService">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.package.myApplicationPackage.BackgroundService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.StartOnBootService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="StartOnBootService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Broadcast receiver name and android manifest receiver name is totally differ.

`StartOnBootService` or in manifest it is `StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver`

Comment: I was editing the code before I posted it and forgot to edit that one, sorry, can you check the edited version?

Comment: @Naskov can you post full logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good practice to look at the manifest file before rushing over stackoverflow.
I also had a similar problem, "crash after boot" and noticed that I had a wrong package name, as a result of a hasty copy paste action for one of my receivers.

```
<receiver android:name="com.somepackage.broadcast.ConnectionChangeReceiver" />
```

was indeed having a typo as

```
<receiver android:name="com.somepackage.broadcast.broadcast.ConnectionChangeReceiver" />
```

Correcting it obviously solved my problem.